# How can I encode a circle in android maps?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps-utils

I know that we can encode a polygon in android like this:

```
  encoded_string = polyutil.encode(polygon.getPoints());
```

But how can we get a encoded string for a circle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `polyutil` is or what its `encode` method does, but a circle's equivalent of a polygon's points is the center and radius.  It shouldn't be too hard to call `getCenter()` and `getRadius()` on the circle and make a string with that data in it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Java Topology Suite to do it.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.11

```
    Coordinate center = new Coordinate(entity.getLongitude(), entity.getLatitude());
    GeometricShapeFactory gsf = new GeometricShapeFactory();

    gsf.setCentre(center);
    gsf.setNumPoints(20);
    gsf.setSize(10.2);

    Polygon poly = gsf.createCircle();

    Coordinate[] coordArray = poly.getCoordinates();
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but it'll give you an array of Coordinates on the perimeter of the circle, so it may be worth playing around with.